# a .sql backup with pqsl won't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows-10, restore, pg-restore

sorry for my stupid question, but I need your help. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

I want to restore a database using pgAdmin 4 and psql on windows 10. I have created a database and an user in pgAdmin 4. Then I open `psql` and execute set role to  and then `\i <name.sql>`. I always get an error.

> No such file or directory.

The file is in

> psql C:/Users/hasan/a.sql

I have set a path in pgAdmin `C:/Program Files/PostgresSQL/9.6/bin`. I have also tried to restore the database with right-click on db in pgAdmin 4. It starts running and nothing happens.

It has been running for hours and hours. The process watcher also doesn't show any information. I don't know what to do. I have tried all solutions from this page and also watched youtube videos. It won't work.

Comment: It can't find `<name.sql>` which I assume is a.sql?.. check it in command promt `CMD>dir file.name.sql` and attach to question, that file is in place

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it is a .sql. The file is in C:/Users/hasan

Comment: so the update your question with `psql C:/Users/hasan/a.sql` command and actual error - copy paste it as is

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
psql -f C:/Users/hasan/a.sql
```

or from inside psql

```
\i "C:/Users/hasan/a.sql"
```